# How to replace width and height an iframe html tag using php?

Tags: php

How to change the width/height if I have the following code and using php:

```
<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/43598400" 
        webkitallowfullscreen="" 
        mozallowfullscreen="" 
        allowfullscreen="" 
        frameborder="0" 
        height="300" 
        width="500">
</iframe>
```

To:

```
<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/43598400" 
        webkitallowfullscreen="" 
        mozallowfullscreen="" 
        allowfullscreen="" 
        frameborder="0" 
        height="400" 
        width="680">
</iframe>
```

Usage is very limited, I want a simple replace solution.

Comment: on which event you need to change the attributes??

Comment: I have the code saved already in a variable, when I am calling it in video page I want to change the width and height to my own set width and height

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like this:

```
$iframe = '<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/43598400" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="300" width="500"></iframe>';

$newWidth = 680;
$newHeight = 400;

$iframe = str_replace('height="300"', 'height="' . $newHeight . '"', $iframe);
$iframe = str_replace('width="500"', 'width="' . $newWidth . '"', $iframe);
```

assuming you are certain that the original width and height will always be 500*300. if not you can try with preg_match()

Answer (score -1):

assuming the variable that holds you string is called `$iframe`, try with

```
str_replace('300', '400', $iframe);
str_replace('500', '680', $iframe);
```

This is, of course, the most hard coded possible solution - show us more of the context in which this iframe code reside if this doesn't help you

Comment: You would use preg_replace, and not str_replace, because...?

Comment: because, 300 might be 123 ... but you are right, for this example `str_replace` is better

Comment: 1. this probably should have been `str_replace`, this isn't even correct preg_replace call. 2. you don't mind replacing those numbers anywhere in the middle of text either, don't you?