# preg_replace custom pattern for maps embbed

Tags: php, preg-replace, expression

Basically I receive this:

```
<iframe width='425' height='350' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' marginheight='0' marginwidth='0' src='https://maps.google.com.br/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=pt-BR&amp;geocode=&amp;q=R.+Alm%C3%A9ria,+242+-+Penha,+S%C3%A3o+Paulo+-+S%C3%A3o+Paulo&amp;aq=0&amp;oq=Rua++Almeria&amp;sll=-14.239424,-53.186502&amp;sspn=79.602428,135.263672&amp;t=h&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=R.+Alm%C3%A9ria,+242+-+Penha,+S%C3%A3o+Paulo,+03654-000&amp;z=14&amp;ll=-23.524401,-46.518859&amp;output=embed'></iframe>
```

What I need to do is to replace any value that is inside the width='' quotes or double quotes with another.

I'm not good with regular expressions, trying to learn by this one seems to be complex.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: You have the HTML in a PHP variable? and want to apply regex to replace the 425 to another value?

Comment: exactly, but 425 can assume any value.

Comment: If this is *your code* why can't you just write the correct value to start with? Or are you scraping from some other site?

Comment: @Marcelo It's not me who will paste this code, it's some random user, the width and height can come with any value.

Answer (score 0):

I answered a similar question not long ago -> [How to replace width and height an iframe html tag using php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11082137/how-to-replace-width-and-height-an-iframe-html-tag-using-php/11082246#11082246)

better use `str_replace()`, it is easier especially if you are not comfortable with regular expressions.

Comment: 425 can assume any value, so I can't use str_replace

Comment: @FelipeZavan yes and str_replace should work perfectly, see my example on my other answer. I store random values in 2 variables wich is used to replace, those values can come from anywhere and don't need to be static.

Answer (score 0):

Find a way to do it, now, 425 ans 350 can be any value, and quoted with single or double quotes:

```
<?php

$embed = "<iframe width=\"425\" height=\"350\" frameborder='0' scrolling='no' marginheight='0' marginwidth='0' src='https://maps.google.com.br/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=pt-BR&amp;geocode=&amp;q=R.+Alm%C3%A9ria,+242+-+Penha,+S%C3%A3o+Paulo+-+S%C3%A3o+Paulo&amp;aq=0&amp;oq=Rua++Almeria&amp;sll=-14.239424,-53.186502&amp;sspn=79.602428,135.263672&amp;t=h&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=R.+Alm%C3%A9ria,+242+-+Penha,+S%C3%A3o+Paulo,+03654-000&amp;z=14&amp;ll=-23.524401,-46.518859&amp;output=embed'></iframe><br /><small><a href='https://maps.google.com.br/maps?f=q&amp;source=embed&amp;hl=pt-BR&amp;geocode=&amp;q=R.+Alm%C3%A9ria,+242+-+Penha,+S%C3%A3o+Paulo+-+S%C3%A3o+Paulo&amp;aq=0&amp;oq=Rua++Almeria&amp;sll=-14.239424,-53.186502&amp;sspn=79.602428,135.263672&amp;t=h&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=R.+Alm%C3%A9ria,+242+-+Penha,+S%C3%A3o+Paulo,+03654-000&amp;z=14&amp;ll=-23.524401,-46.518859' style='color:#0000FF;text-align:left'>Exibir mapa ampliado</a></small>";

var_dump($embed);

$new = preg_replace("/\bwidth='(.*?)'/", "width='100'", $embed);

$new2 = preg_replace("/\bheight='(.*?)'/", "height='100'", $new);

$new3 = preg_replace("/\bwidth=\"(.*?)\"/", "width='100'", $new2);

$new4 = preg_replace("/\bheight=\"(.*?)\"/", "height='100'", $new3);

var_dump($new4);

?>
```